# Can someone look at my Bootstrap Switch onSwitchChange. It does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Not sure what i am doing wrong here other than i am very weak in JQuery.  The code in my onSwitchChange is not working.  If i were to change it and put in alert("something"), it fires the alert, so i assume its in the ajax request.  I have a breakpoint on my controller, but it never even hits the controller.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[name='my-checkbox']" ).bootstrapSwitch({
        onText: "Yes",
        offText: "No",
        onColor: "success",
        offColor: "danger",
        animate: false,
        onSwitchChange: function (event, state) {

                $ajax({
                    url: '/ProposalWork/ChangeActivityStatus/',                        
                    data: { id: @ViewBag.Activity.id, state: state }
                }).done(function () { alert('Status Changed'); });
            }     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a `.` in your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({

})
```

Comment: lol. i'm apparently weak at noticing typos also.  Worked great.  Thanks